# Two java files, in same directory, one accessing the others class/s?

Tags: java, command-line, javac

I am trying to grant one `.java` file access to the class in another `.java` file. I would like to do this on the command line. For example how would I do this using the two files below?

File: "ToImport.java"

```
package ABC;
public class ToImport {
    private String aName;
    public ToImport(String Name)  {
        aName = Name;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return("Text: " + aName);
    }
}
```

File: "TheImport.java"

```
package ABC;
public class TheImport {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        ToImport abc = new ToImport("a");
        System.out.println("TEST: " + abc);
    }
}
```

When I type `javac ToImport.java` I get no errors but when I type `javac TheImport.java` I get the following error,

[image: Command Prompt Error Message]

Comment: in what directory the classes are placed and how and from where you run java

Comment: Most likely you are calling `javac` from the directory in which these two files are located. They both need to be in a directory called "ABC" (the package name), and you'll need to call `javac ABC\TheImport.java` from the directory containing "ABC". That's my guess, anyway.

Comment: since both the files are in the same package and declared public , then you dont need to worry about calling , simply creating the object is enough , but the question is , as jigar has said , how are you compiling it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`TheImport` depends on the class `ToImport`. So, when you compile `TheImport` the compiler must either also compile `ToImport` or have access to the already compiled `ToImport` class.

Let's say you have a directory that looks like the following,

```
src
└── ABC
    ├── TheImport.java
    └── ToImport.java
```

In addition let's say you're in the directory `src` and want to compile to `../classes`. You must use one of the following commands:

```
javac -d ../classes ABC/ToImport.java ABC/TheImport.java
```

or

```
javac -d ../classes ABC/ToImport.java
javac -cp ../classes -d ../classes ABC/TheImport.java
```

If both `.java` files depended on each other then you'd have to compile them both at once as in the first command.

Also note that packages should be all lowercase to respect the Java naming conventions.

To run the main program you could type,

```
cd ../classes
java ABC.TheImport
```

Comment: Perfect answer. You could add external jars while compiling in the `-cp` itself and they should `:` separated. You'll also have to pass the jars while running the class file using `java` command.

Answer (score 3):

From the package containing the .java files run:

```
javac *.java
```

or

```
javac TheImport.java ToImport.java
```

The compiler needs to compile both classes at the same time, it cannot individually compile a single class with dependencies on another.

Comment: The compiler doesn't have to compile both classes at the same time. It can compile one and then compile the other one that depends on it using the `javac` parameter `-cp`, as in the answer to this question by JB Nizet.